# White Loading Screen when Login With Facebook with Facebook sdk: 4.11.0

Tags: android, facebook

I have implemented login with Facebook in my android application. I am using Facebook sdk: **com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0** in my application. When I click on Login With Facebook button from an activity, first it takes me to a blank screen with a Loading text dialogue box and then come back to the activity from where I clicked it and then logged-in into the app.

[image]

I don't want this blank screen to appear, I want to directly login in app from the activity where I clicked the Facebook Login Button.

Please guide me if anyone know how to do this. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

***It's a good practise to try the latest version before thinking about fixing something.***
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x
latest version: 4.22.0

It sounds like your situation is you have already logged-in in facebook app of the device.

Now, facebook sdk default behaviour in this situation: show a small circle loading progressbar center of translucent screen. 
It works as you expected.